# Remove Leading Zero from single digit

Tags: angular, format

I am new to angular and trying to removing the leading zero. Whenever there is single digit in data it gets preceded by 0. I tried to use Pipe for number but it is not working. Is there any way to remove the leading 0 in angular. For instance value is `6` and its becomes `06` which shouldn't. 
I tried `{{file.quantity | number: '2.'}}`.

Comment: Can you show more code. Why are you using the number pipe? I assume that `file.quantity` isn't a number if you have leading zeroes?

Comment: in file.quantity some times its comes 4069109 and some time single digit i.e. 5. So I have to handle both at same time. I have used number pipe to format number is not single digit. So 4069109 becomes 4,069,109.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to format numbers using the number pipe. You can do this without specifying the format.

```html
{{file.quantity | number}}
```

This will format `6` as `6` and `4069109` as `4,069,109`

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zusruo